# how to disable cache for development in django?

Tags: python, django

In some of my templates I'm using the `{% cache %}` template tag to cache some parts, but for development I don't want anything to be cached. I tried using a settings variable to set cache expiring time to zero for dev in a separate settings file and have it called with a `context_processor`, though it's not working.

Does anyone know a way to disable cache for dev environment?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use django dummy caching for development:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
   }
}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs/#dummy-caching-for-development

Answer (score 0):

It can be a problem to make sure your media files, including your stylesheets, are never cached. Here is one way that works for me:

http://lee-phillips.org/djangoStatic/